# Linux claims half full NTFS external drive is out of space

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I've got an external 5TB hard drive formatted as NTFS and mounted in Linux.

When I run `df` I get this info on the drive:

```
/dev/sdd1      4883735548 2398731656 2485003892  50% /media/me/DRIVE0
```

I also tried `df -i` to make sure there were plenty of inodes:

```
/dev/sdd1      2485298804  294284 2485004520    1% /media/me/DRIVE0
```

But when I try to write anything to the drive, it acts like it is full:

```
$ touch /media/me/DRIVE0/test
touch: cannot touch '/media/me/DRIVE0/test': No space left on device
```

This is the most simple example.  It does not help to try to run the command as root. I have also tried rsync (which strangely sometimes claims the device is out of space, and sometimes claims it's copying the files but then nothing is there and error messages occur afterwards), dd, cp, etc.  Originally I was running rsync and had copied a bunch of files when I started getting weird out of space errors and reduced it to this problem.

I tried running ntfsfix but it didn't find any issues.  I also have a second identical drive (model) which is nearly 100% full (40GB free) and I am still able to add files to it with no problem.

I'm at a loss how to troubleshoot this.  I don't currently have access to a Windows machine to try to access the drive from there.

Per the comments I found the following command to get SMART info:

```
sudo smartctl -d sat,16 -a /dev/sdc
```

Here is the output:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-189-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     REDACTED
Serial Number:    REDACTED
LU WWN Device Id: REDACTED
Firmware Version: REDACTED
User Capacity:    5,000,XXX,XXX,XXX bytes [5.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    REDACTED
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   253   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4841
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5604
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       5852
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       230
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       139
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   166   166   000    Old_age   Always       -       102341
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   119   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
```

Comment: ǹtfsfix` at best can signal the drive needs repair with a proper tool and such tool exists only in Windows. If you have access to Windows you should check it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Unfortunately I'm trying to back some stuff up precisely because I don't have access to Windows, but I'm running out of space prematurely

Comment: @ChanganAuto I tried deleting some stuff ($RECYCLE.BIN didn't look necessary) and that freed up 2.7G... I then found I was able to rsync an additional 17GB before I started getting the errors again.

Comment: I keep a couple of easily "portable" Windows VMs for troubleshooting and for situations like this.

Comment: IMHO, if you don't have access to ANY windows machines, then why on earth are you choosing NTFS as your file system?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas LOL.  I didn't say I don't have any Windows machines, just that I don't (currently) have access to any of them

Comment: Can we see SMART. Not saying it will have answers, but you never know...

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Does not seem promising... 3 parameters (Raw_Read_Error_Rate, Spin_Up_Time, and Reallocated_Sector_Ct) say  Pre-fail, and the rest say "Old_age" ... the drive is slightly over 3 years old.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen On the other hand, I'm not positive that I entered the right parameters... it's a USB drive and it failed to autodetect, `-d ata` didn't work but `-d sat,16` did, but I have no idea if that's correct or if it could display erroneous results if it's wrong.

Comment: Add output or screenshot to OP please.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Added

Comment: @ChanganAuto `CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the volume bitmap.`  It doesn't say how much was discovered but... will see how it goes now